# adding multiple menu bars to a JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans

I am making a text editor in java using netbeans and i included JMenuBar in a JFrame. This menu bar holds the basic file and Edit options. i want to add another menubar to same JFrame having options to change font size, font type etc. I tried to add menubar to same JFrame but it didn't work. so please help me with it and also tell me the basics to add options to change font size and font type etc.

```
import java.awt*;
import java.swing*;
public class myForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String ClipBoardData = "";
    String currentFileDirectory= "";
    public myForm() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TextArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        File = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        save = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        saveAs = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        Exit = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        New = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        Edit = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        cut = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        copy = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        paste = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        Delete = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        selectAll = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        /* after this code i'm adding characcters to the objects and preforming  actions on them */
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new myForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
```

But when i try to add menubar in initComponents() i'm not able to edit this function in Netbeans.

Comment: usually you set a JMenuBar using <JFrame>.setJMenuBar(..), but you can also add multiple menu bars using <JFrame>.add(..), if you really need this

Answer (score 0):

> i want to add another menubar to same JFrame having options to change font size, font type etc.

Just add more JMenu's.

> the basics to add options to change font size and font type etc

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for simple editor that does this.

Comment: I got the answer to my question. actually i didn't know about toolkit. now instead of adding another menubar i'm thinking to go for a toolkit and there add a combobox holding all the values of fonts and performing actions.